# Upnp specifications

Tags: .net, upnp, dlna

Hi there i have written a media service that currently supports nfs and was now thinking about adding support for upnp but i don't know where to start is there any rfc or some thing i could read up on as the rfc for nfs where super helpful..
and just to clarify i want to implement it on my own or if there is a pure .net library out there that would also work.

I have no idea where to start?

Edit: i found a few documents [Here](http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/sdcps/) is there any other source of information out there?

Answer (score 2):

You could start at http://www.upnp.org/ and http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/sdcps/ and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382303(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the source code for Coherence (http://coherence.beebits.net/) or ps3mediaserver ([http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver)) to get a good idea of how it is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find the following links helpful:

1. A open-source media server - http://mediatomb.cc/pages/download
2. `libupnp` - Linux SDK for upnp devices - http://upnp.sourceforge.net/

I would also recommend the book [UPnP Design By Example](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_upnp.htm)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason no one gives direct links. And it's hard to find them on the website. For example : http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-MediaServer-v1-Device.pdf
http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-ConnectionManager-v1-Service.pdf